# Unable to add worksheet to EXCEL in powershell

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

I have a working powershell script that executes three SQL queries and writes it to three worksheets in a workbook.

When I try to execute four SQL queries and write it to four worksheets, I get errors, even after including the statement

```
$wb.Worksheets.Add()
```

Here is my code

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT STMT1"

$SQL2 = "SELECT STMT2"

$SQL3 = "SELECT STMT3" 

$SQL4 = "SELECT STMT4" 



# Create Excel file to save the data

if (!(Test-Path -path "$DirectoryToSave")) #create it if not existing 
  { 
  New-Item "$DirectoryToSave" -type directory | out-null 
  } 

$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$wb.Worksheets.Add()
$currentWorksheet=1


$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$ws.name = "GUP Download Activity"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL1)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).VerticalAlignment = $xlTop
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Name = "Calibri" 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Size = 11 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Bold = $true 
}

$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(2)
$ws.name = "Totals"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL2)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).VerticalAlignment = $xlTop
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Name = "Calibri" 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Size = 11 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Bold = $true 
 }


$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(3)
$ws.name = "GUP Downloads per Computer"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL3)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).VerticalAlignment = $xlTop
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Name = "Calibri" 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Size = 11 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Bold = $true 
 }

    $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(4)
    $ws.name = "GUP Monthly Trends"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL4)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).VerticalAlignment = $xlTop
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Name = "Calibri" 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Size = 11 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Bold = $true 
 }



$filename = "D:\Script\Daily_GUP_Report.xlsx"
if (test-path $filename ) { rm $filename } 
$wb.SaveAs($filename,  $xlOpenXMLWorkbook) #save as an XML Workbook (xslx) 
$wb.Saved = $True #flag it as being saved 
$wb.Close() #close the document 
$Excel.Quit() #and the instance of Excel 
$wb = $Null #set all variables that point to Excel objects to null 
$ws = $Null #makes sure Excel deflates 
$Excel=$Null #let the air out
```

Below is the error that is triggered by `$wb.Worksheets.Add()`

```
Application                       : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Creator                           : 1480803660
Parent                            : System.__ComObject
CodeName                          : 
_CodeName                         : 
Index                             : 1
Name                              : Sheet4
Next                              : System.__ComObject
OnDoubleClick                     : 
OnSheetActivate                   : 
OnSheetDeactivate                 : 
PageSetup                         : System.__ComObject
Previous                          : 
ProtectContents                   : False
ProtectDrawingObjects             : False
ProtectionMode                    : False
ProtectScenarios                  : False
Visible                           : -1
Shapes                            : System.__ComObject
TransitionExpEval                 : False
AutoFilterMode                    : False
EnableCalculation                 : True
Cells                             : System.__ComObject
CircularReference                 : 
Columns                           : System.__ComObject
ConsolidationFunction             : -4157
ConsolidationOptions              : {False, False, False}
ConsolidationSources              : 
DisplayAutomaticPageBreaks        : False
EnableAutoFilter                  : False
EnableSelection                   : 0
EnableOutlining                   : False
EnablePivotTable                  : False
FilterMode                        : False
Names                             : System.__ComObject
OnCalculate                       : 
OnData                            : 
OnEntry                           : 
Outline                           : System.__ComObject
Rows                              : System.__ComObject
ScrollArea                        : 
StandardHeight                    : 15
StandardWidth                     : 8.43
TransitionFormEntry               : False
Type                              : -4167
UsedRange                         : System.__ComObject
HPageBreaks                       : System.__ComObject
VPageBreaks                       : System.__ComObject
QueryTables                       : System.__ComObject
DisplayPageBreaks                 : False
Comments                          : System.__ComObject
Hyperlinks                        : System.__ComObject
_DisplayRightToLeft               : False
AutoFilter                        : 
DisplayRightToLeft                : False
Scripts                           : System.__ComObject
Tab                               : System.__ComObject
MailEnvelope                      : 
CustomProperties                  : System.__ComObject
SmartTags                         : System.__ComObject
Protection                        : System.__ComObject
ListObjects                       : System.__ComObject
EnableFormatConditionsCalculation : True
Sort                              : System.__ComObject
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I need to assign the added worksheets to $ws

Instead of

```
$wb.Worksheets.Add()
```

where it's not being assigned, I changed it to

```
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Add()
```